# Select specific one word among multiple words in a dropdown option

Tags: jquery

Need help or pointed in the right direction to select specific words in a dropdown.

For instance, if option 1 - "Team1" vs "Team4" is selected, remove "Team2" and "Team3" from the second dropdown.

```
<select id="gameDrop">
    <option value="1">Team1 vs Team4</option>
    <option value="2">Team2 vs Team3</option>
    <option value="3">Team3 vs Team2</option>
    <option value="4">Team4 vs Team1</option>
</select>

<select id="teamDrop">
    <option value="1">Team1</option>
    <option value="2">Team2</option>
    <option value="3">Team3</option>
    <option value="4">Team4</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way I can extend the following code to select specific words instead of option values in a dropdown?

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('select').not(this).children('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/djg3aufL/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="gameDrop">
    <option value="1:4">Team1 vs Team4</option> // Please note that i have changed the values here
    <option value="2:3">Team2 vs Team3</option>
    <option value="3:2">Team3 vs Team2</option>
    <option value="4:1">Team4 vs Team1</option>
</select>

<select id="teamDrop">
    <option value="1">Team1</option>
    <option value="2">Team2</option>
    <option value="3">Team3</option>
    <option value="4">Team4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#gameDrop').change(function() {
    var $val = $(this).val();
    $val = $val.split(':');
    $('#teamDrop option').prop('disabled',true);
    $.each($val,function(index,value){
        $('#teamDrop option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('disabled',false);
    });
})
```

**CSS** [This is important because this is what hides the unwanted options]

```
select option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```